# A Kotlin observable that multiple clients can subscribe to

Tags: kotlin

Does Kotlin have a built-in observable that multiple clients can subscribe to that allows them to be notified whenever the data in the observable changes? The only thing I found was this:

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.properties/-delegates/observable.html

But this is not really meant to be used by multiple clients. I can always use rxJava but I am looking for something native to Kotlin.

Comment: Maybe `SharedFlow` is what you need? https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-shared-flow/

Comment: Why do you think the built-in observable can't be used by multiple clients? It looks like it can to me.